# Pandas: Index rows by an OR condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter out certain rows in my dataframe that is allowing two combinations of values for two columns. For example columns 'A' and 'B' can just be either 'A' > 0 and 'B' > 0 OR 'A' < 0 and 'B' < 0. Any other combination I want to filter.

I tried the following

```
df = df.loc[(df['A'] > 0 & df['B'] > 0) or (df['A'] < 0 & df['B'] < 0)]
```

which gives me an error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I know this is probably a very trivial questions but I couldn't find any  solution to be honest and I can't figure out what the problem with my approach ist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need some parenthesis and to format for pandas (and/or to become &/|):

```
df = df[((df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] > 0)) | ((df['A'] < 0) & (df['B'] < 0))]
```

Keep in mind what this is doing - you're just building a giant list of [True, False, True, True] and passing that into the df index,  telling it to keep each row depending on whether it gets a True or a False in the corresponding list.

Comment: and specifically to use bitwise operators instead of stand boolean operators (e.g., `&` instead of `and`)

Comment: Also note that for this particular example you can just use `(df["A"] * df["B"] > 0)`

Comment: @ayhan that's true in this case, but not the general rule when trying to have multiple criteria

Comment: @ayhan that misses the point of the OP, which is trying to use multiple conditions in a `.loc` statement

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to figure it out with the pandas-docs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) on indexing but I couldn't figure out how many parenthesis I need to have. I wasn't expecting to have parentheses for each evaluation for the condition on the columns.

Comment: I agree. That's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @TheDude `wasn't expecting to have parentheses for each evaluation for the condition` strictly speaking, you don't. but they keep things tidy and easy to read (to me)