# Retrieve data from two columns of csv file based on user input

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this csv file named sample.csv:

```
CODE     HOME_TEAM     AWAY_TEAM 
0001        Lakers          Jazz          
0002       Raptors        Lakers             
0003      Warriors      Portland           
0004     Mavericks        Lakers          
0005       Celtics     Mavericks
```

I wish to print every game the team participated based on the user input.  Suppose that in the example above, the user inputs "Lakers," the program should print:

```
CODE     HOME_TEAM     AWAY_TEAM 
0001        Lakers          Jazz          
0002       Raptors        Lakers                     
0004     Mavericks        Lakers
```

So far, what I've coded (see below) prints the information separately.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

select_Team = input("Which team do you like to see: ")
df2 = df[df["HOME_TEAM"] == select_Team]
df3 = df[df["AWAY_TEAM"] == select_Team]
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

What should I do to present the information as one (like the one I've shown above)?

Comment: join the conditions using `or`? [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330964/14739759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include both conditions

```
df2 = df[(df["HOME_TEAM"] == select_Team) | (df["AWAY_TEAM"] == select_Team)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `eq` with `any` PS is the team is more than one change `eq` to `isin`

```
out = df[df.eq('Lakers').any(1)] # df[df.isin(['Lakers']).any(1)]
Out[462]: 
   CODE  HOME_TEAM AWAY_TEAM
0     1     Lakers      Jazz
1     2    Raptors    Lakers
3     4  Mavericks    Lakers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create some logic to raise a value error if the team entered is not in the DataFrame:

```
select_Team = input("Which team do you like to see: ")

df2 = df[(df['HOME_TEAM'].str.lower() == select_Team.lower()) | (df['AWAY_TEAM'].str.lower() == select_Team.lower())]
if len(df2) == 0:
    raise ValueError(f"{select_Team} is not in the DataFrame. The teams available are {set(df[['HOME_TEAM', 'AWAY_TEAM']].stack())}")
else:
    print(df2)
```